# Kinematics on Lie groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The following problem has recently come up in the course of a project I'm working on, and I would be very appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction:

Let $X \colon I \to G$ be a smooth curve taking values in a Lie group $G$ with a surjective exponential map, and define another curve $v\colon I \to T_e(G)$ according to $v(t) \triangleq \omega_{X(t)}\left( \dot{x}(t) \right)$, where $\omega$ is the Maurer-Cartan form on $G$.  Then intuitively, $v(t)$ represents a kind of "local" measurement of the velocity $\dot{X}(t)$, expressed in a local, "co-moving" coordinate system that is rigidly attached to the point $X(t)$ itself.

Given access to $v(t)$ and an initial condition of the form $X(t_0) = X_{t_0} \in G$ for some $t_0 \in I$, I would like to determine a curve $\gamma \colon I \to T_e(G)$ such that $X = \exp \circ \gamma$.

Comment: Existence and uniqueness of $\gamma$, for absolutely continuous $v(t)$, follows immediately from Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations. These equations $x^{-1}dx=v(t) dt$ are called *Lie equations*.  Smoothness of $X(t)$ is not clear to me, although it will be smooth for solvable Lie groups because the exponential map is a diffeomorphism. Look at $SU(2)$ to see the problem in general: the exponential map is very bad as you pass through $-I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(t)$ is widely used, even for a proof of existence of a Lie group for a given Lie algebra (see the book of Duistermaat and Kolk).

It is also used a lot for infinite dimensional Lie groups where the exponential map is not a local diffeomorphism, in general (for diffeomorphism groups, for example). See the book "Younes: Shapes and diffeomorphisms" or the overview article  [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/shape-overview.pdf).

As pointed out by Ben MacKay, even in finite dimensions, the exponential mapping might not be a diffeomorphism everywhere, or it might not be surjective. See the following very nice article for illustrations of this:

- MR0808680 Hilgert, Joachim; Hofmann, Karl H. Old and new on Sl(2). Manuscripta Math. 54 (1985), no. 1-2, 17–52.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the case of $SU(2)$ is very typical, since so many Lie groups contain $SU(2)$. If you just make the curve $x(t)$ head to $-I$ as it slows down and then stops at $-I$, so that the velocity and all of its derivatives go to zero, and then turns in some random direction, you can easily build a smooth curve $x(t)$ so that $x(t)=e^{X(t)}$ only for discontinuous $X(t)$. Just draw the picture for the 2-sphere, and then remember that the exponential map of the 3-sphere is the exponential map of its standard round metric.

On the other hand, if there is no copy of $SU(2)$ or $SO(3)$ or $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ in your Lie group, then there is such an $X(t)$, since the universal covering space of your Lie group has exponential map a diffeomorphism, if I remember correctly, so you build $X(t)$ up there and then project it to $G$. (My favourite reference for this sort of stuff is Hilgert and Neeb.)

The case of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ should be easy to check by hand, since the exponential map is manageable.